# App/homepage bottom bar with social/contact buttons looking similar to Android navigation bar. Problem?

Tags: web-app, mobile-application, android, footers, bottom-navigation

The context is a single page webapp which will also be served as a webview Android app. The target audience is 18+.

As it is designed right now, the social/contact icons are placed in a fixed footer/bottom bar.

Now this bottom bar looks eerily similar to the navigation bar in the android home screen.

1. Is this a problem UI/UX wise?
2. Could this be a problem play store policy wise?

What might be possible solutions? Make the footer non-fixed?
[image: screenshot of app homepage]

Update/Add: The buttons aren't exactly "social buttons" but more like "contact buttons". So touching the IG icon will open the IG page of the app. Touching the call icon will open up the phone dialer with the company number pre-entered. Touching the Whatsapp button will open up a Whatsapp message template to the company number. Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better idea would be this:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is a good idea actually. Thanks. What symbol do you think should the icon have in my case? Obviously not a big plus cuz the user is not adding some content per se.. But something related to getting in touch.. pen/phone/___? But then what if the first time user is not a fan of the whatever symbol is shown. How is he to know there's more icons that will show up on touching that?

Comment: Maybe just the word "contact" ?

Comment: Of course not plus in your example. It is just an idea. Something related to media will work. I think whatever icon you use, make it more contrast so that User tends to click on it. And if this answer suits you, accept this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This could cause a UX problem.
For information on how to properly use a Bottom navigation, check this info by [Material Design.](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation#placement)

Think about when people want to use social features (sharing something). Place the option to share into a drawer/ button that triggers the view right next to the item that is being shared. If it was supposed to contact the person yo uare chatting with, put this option in the persons profile.

There is no behavioral reason to show the social media icons/buttons the whole time.

Comment: Good points. Actually, those buttons aren't exactly "social buttons" but more like "contact buttons". So touching the IG icon will open the IG page of the app. Touching the call icon will open up the phone dialer with the company number. Touching the Whatsapp button will open up a Whatsapp message template to the company number. Etc. I just updated the question with this info. Does this affect your opinion?

Comment: Well, if that is the case, stuff like this belongs either into the footer or onto the contact page (or both).